# Data structure for real world path

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, geolocation

In a discussion, I was asked to store a real world path between two points P and Q on earth. It can have straight lines or curved lines or can have unlimited direction changes.

I can use any database (schema defined by me) or file system, so that I can recreate the (almost) same path from the stored information.

Objective here is to use less space and be more accurate when recreating path from stored information.

What structure should I use for paths? I can store straight lines and curves which are circle, with Geo-coordinates. But how to store other types of and unconventional curves?

Comment: When you say "less space" and "more accurate", what algorithm do you compare it to? What is your baseline and what have you tried so far?

Comment: Also the `path` tag is for linux directories, please remove it. You can add `data-structures` and `geography` tags.

Comment: @Yonlif I tried for straight lines and circles. But I don't know how to work with other curves.

Answer (score 1):

> You can store any type of curve as a set of points just like circles and polygons.

One way to represent curves by points is [Bezier curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve). Here, a curve is constructed out of a set of points (i.e. starting point, ending point and control points). Bezier curves are used in computer graphics to draw shapes, for CSS animation and in many other places.

Example  1: One control point

[image: example 1]

Example 2: Three control points

[image: example 2]

- Images are taken from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve)